# Alternative notions of bisimulation

Tags: reference-request, automata-theory, pl.programming-languages, process-algebra, lts-simulations

Suppose $(S, \Lambda, \rightarrow)$ is a labeled transition system. A *bisimulation* is a relation $R \subseteq S \times S$ s.t. $\forall \alpha \in \Lambda$ and $\forall p, q \in S$ with $R(p,q)$,

- $\forall p'. p \xrightarrow{\alpha} p' \implies \exists q' . q \xrightarrow{\alpha} q' \land R(p',q');$
- $\forall q'. q \xrightarrow{\alpha} q' \implies \exists p' . p \xrightarrow{\alpha} p' \land R(p',q').$

I noticed that for this definition of bisimulation, if $p$ can take an $\alpha$-step, then so can $q$ and vice-versa. I.e., the transition-labels $\alpha \in \Lambda$ are are *syntactically* the same. But what if the transition system labels allow for value-passing? E.g., $\alpha(x) \triangleq \text{send}(x)$, the action of sending a value $x$ to some location. Then clearly $\text{send}(x) \neq \text{send}(y)$ when $x \neq y$, but we might want to consider two systems as doing the "same action" if $x$ and $y$ belong to some equivalence class (or even just some relation), even if they are not *syntactically* the same value.

So, modify the definition as so: Let $\approx \subseteq \Lambda \times \Lambda$ be some relation. Let $R\subseteq S \times S$ be a relation s.t. $\forall \alpha \in \Lambda$, $\forall p,q\in S$ with $R(p,q)$,

- $\forall p'. p \xrightarrow{\alpha} p' \implies \exists \beta, q'. \alpha \approx \beta \land q \xrightarrow{\beta} q' \land R(p',q');$
- $\forall q'. q \xrightarrow{\alpha} q' \implies \exists \beta, p' . \alpha \approx \beta \land p \xrightarrow{\beta} p' \land R(p',q').$

If we take $\approx$ to be syntactic equality $\equiv$, we recover the original definition of bisimulation.

My question: Has this form of bisimulation been studied? What is it called? In particular, I'm interested in workable definitions of (bi)simulation in a system which allows value-passing, where we might want to allow some set of OK values, rather than restrict to syntactic equality of actions.

More generally, I am interested in alternative definitions of bisimulation which lead to notions of "observational equivalence".

Comment: There has been a lot of work on different notions of process equivalence in the 1990s. Rob van Glabbeek's *The Linear Time - Branching Time Spectrum* Parts 1 and 2 are places to start looking. In the context of $\pi$-calculus you have *early* and *late* bisimulations, and b/c you can extrude scope, you will certainly want to equate $\alpha$-equivalent output-transitions. In higher-order process calculi, where you can pass processes (so they show up in labels) the question comes up as well.

Comment: Your notion of bisimulation is just the standard one where you consider the set of labels to be $\Lambda/\!\approx$ (the equivalence classes) rather than $\Lambda$.  So there's nothing you can do with your definition that you can't do with the usual one.  Or maybe you want to say something different?

Comment: @DamianoMazza One can repackage the standard definition of bisimulation into a coalgebraic definition (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisimulation#Coalgebraic_definition)). This gives a nice characterization of bisimulation as a particular kind of commuting diagram. It is not obvious to me how things here change when considering equivalence classes instead of syntactic equality. This is one of the main examples I had in mind with this question.

Comment: Suppose you have an lts $S$ with labels $\{a,b,c\}$.  You decide that $a$ and $b$ should be equivalent, so you take $S$, rename all transitions labelled by $a$ or $b$ to a new label $d$, and get an lts $S'$ on $\{c,d\}$.  The usual definition of bisimulation for $S'$ corresponds exactly to your modified bisimulation on $S$, in the sense that $p$ and $p'$ will be bisimilar in $S'$ iff they are bisimilar in $S$ in your sense.  Also, the coalgebraic reformulation you are interested in applies without changes to $S'$.  You just needed to relabel things.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: Since you mention "observational equivalence", there are also *weak* notions of process equivalences, where, simplifying a bit, strings $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are considered equal if $\hat{\sigma}_1 = \hat{\sigma}_2$ where the function $\hat{\cdot}$ removes invisible actions.  If your model of computing is un-timed, you will need something like this for observational equivalency, since in such a setting, internal compute steps  cannot be observed.

Comment: A useful model for thinking about observational equivalence is that computational steps are given unlabelled: $P \rightarrow Q$. Observational equivalence is defined as closure under all possible context using $\rightarrow$. Now reasoning about process (in)equality wrt all possible context is annoying, so you use labelled transitions as convenience: a proof techniques for reasoning about process (in)equality where labels represent *minimal distinguishing contexts*: if you can say something about a process wrt minimal context, this then can (often) be used to say something about all contexts.